# How to select specific form control checkboxes in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am working in Excel 2010.

I have set up 10 form control checkboxes in my worksheet, and I want to automatically select a certain set of the checkboxes.  All previous posts that I have seen on this topic cover selecting all checkboxes or unselecting all checkboxes.

Here is the VBA code from a previous post for unselecting all checkboxes:

```
Sub clearcheck() 
Dim sh As Worksheet For Each sh In Sheets 
On Error Resume Next 
sh.CheckBoxes.Value = False 
On Error GoTo 0 Next sh 
End Sub
```

Here is the updated code based on this chain, but it is still running into a syntactical issue as well as an unidentified sub:

```
Sub highengagedonline() 
Dim cb As CheckBox, sht As Worksheet 
Set sht = Worksheets("Graph") 
For Each cb In sht.CheckBoxes 
    If cb.Name = "Check Box 35" or _
       cb.Name = "Check Box 36" or _
       cb.Name = "Check Box 37" or _
       cb.Name = "Check Box 38" or _
       cb.Name = "Check Box 39" Then
           cb.Value = 1 
    Else: cb.Value = 0 
    End If 
Next cb 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the checkboxes all on one sheet? How will you decide which ones to automatically select? By name?

Comment: All of the checkboxes are on one sheet. My plan was to identify the name of each checkbox and call them out in the script.  I have a set of code that determines the name for each checkbox, but i could be persuaded to do it differently if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub ClearCheck()
    Dim cb As CheckBox, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each cb In sht.CheckBoxes
        If cb.Name = "Check Box 1" Then  
            cb.Value = 1
        Else if cb.Name = "Check Box 2" Then
            cb.Value = 0
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry i'm being a little dense here - but would you be able to show an example of selecting a "Check Box 1" to be checked and a "Check Box 2" to be unchecked?

Comment: I've updated the code. This is the 'brute force' way. It could be better. What criteria are you using to determine which chkboxes are on / off?

Comment: On the excel sheet, I have three form control buttons that execute macros.  I want each macro to select and un select a combination (predetermined) of check boxes. Does cb.Value = 1 check the check box?

Comment: Yes `cb.Value = 1` checks the check box. (You can also write `cb.Value = true` if you prefer)

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex.  If I have multiple checkboxes I want to set to true and false, should add all of the Trues before the elae if and all of the falses before the end if?

Comment: You can do it that way but you don't have to. What is important is that you use the `if...else if...` syntax to identify the ones to check and uncheck.

Comment: first uncheck all the checkboxes and then check only those which needs to be checked, you can create a mapping as well to identify the cases\

Comment: So I've started to implement the code and i'm now running into a few syntax errors. Additionally, the Sub is being flagged as a unidentified.  I've added the updated code to the questions section.

Comment: The identifier under cursor is not identified - My cursor is pointing to "Sub highengagedonline ()" part of the code